# Posts not reflecting correct preview when URL shared on Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I have been on this for days now. Here's my problem:

When I share the URL's for my posts and some of my pages, it appends "Page Not Found" to the Title (og:title) and shows a random string for the Description (og:description). It works fine for most of my pages, but not for some and all of my posts.

Here is an example of a URL that is not working when shared on Facebook:

http://filminstitute.upd.edu.ph/event/saving-sally/?instance_id=207

Please take a look:

[image]

When posting the URL of a page that works, this is what it looks like and what is supposed to be happening:

[image]

When I run my URL's in the Facebook Share Debugger, here is what I been getting:

[image]

[image]

I initially believed that the problem could be solved by adding the following meta tags to the header of the Website like this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php get_permalink() ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php get_header_image(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="UP Film Institute" />
```

But as you can see in the images I provided, the title and description meta have not responded to the tags in the header.

Other things I have tried:

1. Changing the OG meta from the functions.php - nothing changed
2. Installing Yoast SEO - nothing changed
3. Performed a command line search on all the plugin files for code snippets that manipulate og:description - 1 instance found, commented out, nothing changed

Can anyone point me in the right direction regarding what to do with this? I have been working on this problem for days now.

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please include example URLs in text form for easy copy&paste.

Comment: Hi, here is an example of a post that is not working on Facebook: http://filminstitute.upd.edu.ph/event/saving-sally/?instance_id=207

Comment: When I check that using f.e. http://web-sniffer.net/, then it shows a 404 response, too. Go check if you have any plugins installed that try and block requests from “bots”.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response, I will go ahead and check this out.

Comment: You might also try to debug your WordPress 404. Try to use this https://gist.github.com/soulseekah/2321074

Comment: This is strange. Posts are not showing up when viewed from the USA, but are visible to people in Hong Kong. This would lead me to think it has something to do with my host, but of course this is only my speculation. Right now I am still checking my plugins for blockages against requests from bots. My command line search turned out a lot of results and it will take days to go over all of them. For reference, here is the search I am using: "findstr /s /i /n /m /c:"robots" *.*" thanks for your responses. I would like to solve this problem and document it for the benefit of others.

Comment: Just looked at the HTML for the URL, I see multiple instances of og:title and og:description. That might also throw the expected results off. Make sure you only set them once.

Comment: CBroe, I been seeing your name in the answers section of very similar problems to this on throughout the years. Is the source of the problem the same for all the other guys? This seems to be a common issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You sample url shows

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Array"/>
```

might be an issue with the printing the image url using your **get_header_image** function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not Facebook at all. It's DNS. When I was at home, I posted the following:

> If you go to the page directly in your browser,
>   "Page not found" is literally a part of the title
>   (http://filminstitute.upd.edu.ph/screening-and-events) because the
>   page doesn't exist. You need to use the correct URL
>   (http://filminstitute.upd.edu.ph/screenings-and-events/) and then
>   Facebook will resolve on its own. Typos are evil things ;)
>
> Likewise,
>   http://filminstitute.upd.edu.ph/event/saving-sally/?instance_id=207
>   doesn't go to a valid page. That looks like a permalink issue. I
>   noticed the search on the site doesn't work either. Before trying to
>   solve Facebook, I'd look into why you're getting a slew of 404s.
>
> Otherwise, you're basically sharing the contents of your 404 page.

When I visited the website at work, the site looked COMPLETELY different and the links passed through fine. If the site DNS is breaking, then I'd bet on Facebook actually pulling the old one, and since those links may not have existed, that's why you're getting the 404 issues.

This is what I see at home:

[image: what I saw at home]

Comment: Hi, the one you see at home is the old website from 2011. The one at work is the one I have been commissioned to redesign. After cloning my website to a separate machine and hosting it from there, the meta tags from the cloned website are being read by Facebook, and it is working fine. This points in the direction of the problem originating from the side of the hosting provider. I also discovered through exhaustive reading and scouring of Stack Overflow that the problem is indeed DNS. The hosting provider also mentioned that Facebook uses IPV6 and that my Website's IPV4 still used the old~

Comment: (Continued from previous comment) My website's IPV4 address still pointed to the old design, which did not have the new OG Meta Tags. The intricacies of IPV4 and IPV6 are things that I have not gotten about to learning yet so it took me this long to figure it out. I hope this problem is given attention so that others will know how to solve it quicker. Now I wait 48 hours for DNS propagation to take place. If it works out and Facebook starts to pick up my Meta, tell you what you can have my bounty.

Comment: The problem has been solved. The bounty is yours :))

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the property in your header file from this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php get_header_image(); ?>" />
```

To this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo esc_url( get_header_image() ); ?>" />
```

Comment: It wasn't my code that isn't working. It was a DNS issue all along. My host properly set up the Website's IPV4 address but paid no attention to it's IPV6. Facebook was pulling the meta tags from the IPV6 address which didn't exist.